# gwt CellList edit cell

Tags: list, gwt, cell, edit

```
CellList<Device> cellList = new CellList<Device>(new ItemCell());
```

where:

```
static class ItemCell extends AbstractCell<Device> {
    @Override
    public void render(Context context, Device device, SafeHtmlBuilder builder) {
        if(device == null) {
            return;
        }
        builder.appendHtmlConstant("<div>device.getId()</div>");
        builder.appendHtmlConstant("<div>device.getName()</div>");
    }
}
```

And now, I want to make an 'Edit' button, when I'll press on it - I want to see editable selected item. How can I do it? Please answer, who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the simple old way of doing this.

I used a cell list and a form attached to it. Every time you click on a row, row's data is loaded to the form. You can delete or edit the selected row via this form now.

Answer (score 1):

Use EditTextCell or ActionCell

```
addColumn(new EditTextCell(), "Name", new GetValue() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(IData contact) {
                return contact.getName();
            }
        }, new FieldUpdater() {
            @Override
            public void update(int index, IData object, String value) {
                try {
                    pandingChanges.add(new FirstNameChange(object, value));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
```

`}
    });`

check [this](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler) out or >[THIS](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/cell/CwCellSampler.java?r=8511#310)>

Comment: Thank you, mr. wingdings. But I have a CellList, not CellTable, what is method addColumn() in CellList ?